# How to parallelise Bayesian network structure learning

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bnlearn

How can I parallelize the `hc` algorithm from the package `bnlearn`? For example, how can I update the following code

```
bn_k2 <- hc(x = dTrain, score = "k2",debug = F, optimized = T)
```

My pc has 8 Core and when I run  `hc` just one CPU is used. How can I make to run on all 8 Core ?

Comment: Your question is overly broad. You don't establish what problem you're actually trying to solve nor what you've tried so far. And you don't give a complete reproducible example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: as far as I know, only the constraint based algorithms are parallelised.

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad or the problem unstated; it is specific in wanting to parallelise the hc algorithm - this feature is present on other algorithms.

Comment: @sergio; R by default runs on one core. `hc` does not currently support parallel search. If you are willing to use constraint learning, you can do the search in parallel. If you are wanting to use a parallel search because it is taking too long (many variables), you could try a hybrid search i.e. `mmhc`, which can be a lot faster in this case

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to paralelize the algorithm to make it faster or to run it on multiple data sources at once?
If it the first case probably you need to rewrite the function. If it's the second, just use the package `parallel` to handle with the loop.

Comment: My CPU has 8 cores and I would like to use all but when run the bc them use just 1 CPU,.How to make all CPU use, you can show an example?